# Is there any way to capture the screen shot of the entire page using selenium RC on IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium-rc

I use Java for scripting. i have tried using the ROBOT class, but i am still not able to capture what is on the entire page(i get the screen dimensions and capture the image, if an extra value is added to the height/width the Page content is not captured where as a black screen is added). In short is there any way to implement captureEntirePageScreenShot() for IE.
Thanks in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to capture the entire screen or entire page? If the page needs to scrolled down, I dont think you can capture that in Selenium. It may be possible in Se2.

Comment: Thanks Rajsankar. I do want to capture the the entire Page, i do need to scroll down. is there no way to do this using Java if not Selenium alone?

Comment: Nope. AFIK it is not possible. I think there is no way you can extract the entire page in Java. May be you need to post a new question with Java tag

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using [snapsIE](http://snapsie.sourceforge.net/)?
I haven't used it but from what I have read, it may solve your problem.

Is getting the HTML source of the page an option?

Any particular reason you can't use Firefox?
I currently use Selenium RC, called from .Net and using Firefox to capture large screens, bigger than the browser view port.

Comment: Just in case others may reach here for the same question (like me), snapsIE does not work for RC now. It only works for iexploreproxy mode (as mentioned by author), which is not supported by latest selenium RC. One possible work around is to modify the source code of snapsIE and change it to do full screen capture instead of browser capture. Or, you may want to use selenium WebDriver instead.